# Bluetooth can't turn on

Tags: bluetooth

Just updated my BIOS (Lenovo recommended) on my Yoga 920.

Bluetooth was working prior, and now when I navigate to the Bluetooth Dialog, I can click on the 'turn on' button but trying to turn on Bluetooth just does nothing.

Bluetooth works in Windows but NOT in Ubuntu.

I found other threads like this, one of them asked for the output of the following terminal command.

Any help?

[image: terminalOutput]

```
eljamoquio@DrFancyPants:~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for eljamoquio: 
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Second command:**

```
dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; rfkill list; hciconfig -a
[    0.032937] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.056592] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.344917] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    2.344867] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.344879] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.344881] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.344883] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.344886] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.919518] ath10k_pci 0000:6b:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:6b:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.919524] ath10k_pci 0000:6b:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:6b:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.922052] ath10k_pci 0000:6b:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    5.862936] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.862937] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.862940] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**third command**

```
lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             548864  10 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
```

I haven't found a bluetooth command in the BIOS, and I certainly would be surprised if there was a command in the BIOS that allowed Bluetooth in Windows but somehow disabled it in Ubuntu.  I mean that might be a undocumented side effect but I wouldn't know how to start to get that sort of function.

**Fourth command**

```
 sudo modprobe btusb
[sudo] password for eljamoquio: 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Required key not available
```

**Fifth command**

```
dkms status
anbox, 1, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
anbox, 1, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb, 4.0, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb, 4.0, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Sixth....

```
sudo dkms remove btusb/4.0 --all && sudo dkms uninstall btusb/4.0
[sudo] password for eljamoquio: 

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  btusb
Version: 4.0
Kernel:  4.15.0-42-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

btusb.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic to /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  btusb
Version: 4.0
Kernel:  4.15.0-43-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

btusb.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic to /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.0
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Error! There are no instances of module: btusb
located in the DKMS tree.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; rfkill list; hciconfig -a`

Comment: Done.   Typing this short sentence adds enough characters to post.

Comment: Is there an option in BIOS that enables Bluetooth?  It actually showed in the lsusb results as 0cf3:e300  Please edit to include results for `lsmod | grep blue`

Comment: Done.  No, I haven't found a BIOS option for bluetooth, and I'd be surprised if there was a setting that would allow Bluetooth in Windows (it works in Windows) but somehow disallows it in Ubuntu.  C

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe btusb` and sit down

Comment: Hmmm, I was already sitting when I tried the command.  Does the order matter?    It got an error, FYI.  I'm going to try rebooting now and try it again.

Comment: Post results for `dkms status`

Comment: Done!  Plus I learned the '<pre>' command.

Comment: `sudo dkms remove btusb/4.0 --all && sudo dkms uninstall btusb/4.0` Reboot

Comment: Done.  Bluetooth works!  Anything else you'd like me to do?  If this happens again, should I jump to the last step?